# filling teeth and place a filling

Tags: grammar

> Her filling was dropped out and have to ***filling teeth***.
>
> Her filling was dropped out and have to ***place a filling***.

Is "place a filling" the alternative way to say "filling teeth"?

Answer (score 2):

Neither is correct English. You would instead say "Her filling has dropped out, and she needs a tooth filled."

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the originals are correct.

I don't mind 'dropped out', but definitely not 'was dropped out' which is ungrammatical, however, the form I'd prefer would be...

> "Her filling came out, so she needed a replacement."
>   or perhaps
>   "Her filling came out, so she needed a new one"

I prefer the second option, from J.R.'s comment, without the extra 'to get', but the first option would be my choice.

I don't like any of the constructions that link the two clauses with *'and'*
*'So'* implies causality - because her filling came out, she needed a new one.
*'And'* merely strings the ideas together in the order they possibly happened.

Interestingly, you can 'replace a filling' but you really can't 'place' one.
You would 'have a tooth filled' or 'get a filling', or 'have a filling' [possibly, but that's very colloquial]

Answer (score 1):

All the sentences seem unnatural and incorrect. I think it can be rephrased
as follows:

> "Her filling came out and she had to have another filling".
>   "Her filling came out and she had another filling".
>   "Her filling came out and she had the tooth filled again".

I am not sure if we can use dropped out instead of came out.

Comment: I've never heard "dropped out" in this sense in AmE.  I would expect "came out" or "fell out."  You might also say, "she had her filling replaced" or "she had her tooth refilled."

Comment: Or, perhaps more simply, "Her filling came out so she needed to **get a new one**."